# How to unpack a parent object into a extended child constructor?

Tags: scala

I am looking to splat an object into a constructor that accepts all pairs in that object.

```
case class Cat(name: String) 
case class PetPersian(name: String, price: Number) 

val c1 = Cat(name = "Meowth")

val c2 = PetPersian( 
  c1, // this is what I am trying to reuse.
  price = 10000
)
```

Comment: Is not possible our of the box, there are some tricks to make something similar to work using **Shapeless** or **Monocle**. But, I personally would juts use the case class directly rather than repeat fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom constructor in the companion object which will make the code work.

```
object PetPersian {
   def apply(cat: Cat, price: Number): PetPersian = PetPersian(cat.name, price)
}
```

If there is a need to accept a number of different types in the constructor, declare a common `trait` for those types or use a typeclass.

If you want to make it work with any object with a `name` field it can be done using a structural type which has performance and other issues and is not recommended.

```
object PetPersian {
   def apply(n: { def name: String }, price: Number): PetPersian = PetPersian(n.name, price)
}
```